# logging http POST in apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

We've got a django webapp running that receives http POST submissions from a variety of clients.

We'd like to be able to have apache log the specific http POSTs coming in before they reach our web app.  We see this is an insurance against anything catastrophic being wrong with django.

I've looked at [mod-security](http://www.modsecurity.org/projects/modsecurity/apache/index.html) and its stripped down cousin [mod_log_post](http://freshmeat.net/projects/mod_log_post).  mod_log_post seems to have been made in response to the bigness of mod-security being overkill, and I am inclined to agree.  The relative newness and lack of community around  mod_log_post is a bit of a concern.  `mod_dumpio` seems too much of a blunt instrument in turning on a firehose of too much information.  We know the nature and even the URLs in which this POST data is coming in and we want to specifically target logging of those POST events.

Are there other options for apache to accomplish this level of logging?
Are there recommended config options for mod-security or the other mods?

Comment: Related question at Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989967/best-way-to-log-post-data-in-apache

Comment: https://github.com/danghvu/mod_dumpost (from the other post)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry, that mod_log_post is a one-man-show right now, but the feature set is fixed, too. POST data is POST data, there's not much hands and community needed.