# Is it possible to make apache print http parameters in access log?

Tags: apache-2.2, http, website, web

Apache prints the request to access log. The line will tell you which page is access, say test.php but is it possible to ask it to log the HTTP post parameters as well? Ideally, a specific parameter?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible.  I found several references to various methods, depending on whether you want just a set of parameters or a full data dump of POSTed data.

- Use [`mod_dumpio`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-mod_dumpio-log-post-data/).  This can dump all input and output (separately, if desired) the server receives.  (The same post suggests `mod_security` but doesn't detail a configuration.)
- Use [`mod_log_post`](http://freshmeat.net/projects/mod_log_post) ([download](http://ftp.robert-scheck.de/linux/mod_log_post/)).  Apparently it's a stripped-down cousin of `mod_security`.  See this somewhat related [ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/51295/logging-http-post-in-apache).
- [Don't](http://www.usenet-forums.com/linux-web-servers/6226-apache-2-0-parameters-post-method-custom-logfile.html#post20195); instead, log inputs from your script directly.  (This is due to security concerns -- a malicious attacker could flood your server with POST requests and fill up the logfile partition.)

Comment: + for last point.

Answer (score 0):

Not by default not with the [**mod_log_config**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html) module as far as I know.

You might want to check [**these instructions**](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-mod_dumpio-log-post-data/) using the [**mod_dumpio**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dumpio.html) module.